# ExpressionEngine and Amazon SES

Tags: solspace-freeform, ee3, aws

I am trying to send email from ExpressionEngine using Amazon's Simple Email Service via SMTP and I can't get this working.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html provides direction on how to connect. I configured EE3 outgoing email in the following way:

- **Server Address:** email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- **Server Port:** 587 (I've also tried 25)
- **Username:** [my AWS-provided SMTP user credential]
- **Password:** [my AWS-provided SMTP user credential]
- **Connection Type:** STARTTLS (I've also tried SSL and unencrypted)

I've tried all of the port/connection combinations that I can think of. Some of them throw a PHP fsockopen() error. Other times no error is thrown and FreeForm shows a successful submission screen, but SES never got the request to send a message.

What is the correct way to configure EE to work with SES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you're working with EE3, but I've got SES working successfully on all my production sites that run various flavours of EE 2 (2.8.1, 2.10.2). The settings you've listed above are exactly what I have setup in my email configuration.

I'm hoping that my config file should point you in the right direction.
Perhaps the **email_newline** setting is what is missing from your local configuration?

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Amazon SES
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
*/
$config['email_smtp_crypto'] = 'tls'; // TLS protocol - this needs to be added to each index.php
$config['email_newline'] = "\r\n";  // SES hangs with just \n
```

Other than that, it's most likely an Amazon SES configuration issue.
When you first sign up to use the service, you are placed in a sandbox mode - meaning you can only send and receive from domains you have verified.

Have you verified the domains you are sending from and to?

Comment: Thank you for that. I ended up writing an extension to access SES' API since the SMTP route wasn't going my way.